React Native Navigation issue - Properly 'navigation' doesn't exist
I tried for a long time to do a simple practice to navigate page in react-native but the program still shows "Properly 'navigation' doesn't exist", all navigation components are installed and pod already be installed again, please help...... thank you so much.
Hope anyone can help to solve the problem, much appreciate!
import React from 'react';
import type {PropsWithChildren} from 'react';
import Main from './basic/main';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

import {
    SafeAreaView
    ScrollView,
    StyleSheet,
    Text, 
    useColorScheme,
    View,
    Button,
  } from 'react-native';

import {
    Colors,
    DebugInstructions,
    Header,
    ReloadInstructions,
  } from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

type SectionProps = PropsWithChildren<{
    title: string;
  }>;

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App(): React.JSX.Element {

  function HomeScreen() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screenxxx</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  function DetailsScreen({ navigation }) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Details Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Details... again"
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }


  return (
      <ScrollView
        contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
        style={backgroundStyle}>
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
          }}>


    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{ title: 'Overview' }}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} options={{ title: 'Overview' }}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    <Button
    title="Go to Details... again"
    onPress={() => navigation.push('Details')}
    />
    
    </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

export default App;


It looks like navigation isn't declared in your App component, so when Button tries to access navigation, it is undefined.
You can do 3 things here:
1.) use the Ref prop in the Navigation Container, then call navigation using the ref. Example in the Apollo docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/navigation-container/#ref
2.) Move your Button component inside the NavigationContainer, so that it has access to navigation
3.)If App is wrapped inside of a navigation component, grab the navigation function from App's props.

sorry I am not sure about it, could you give me some example for my code? Thanks
